# Invertibility of Matrix with Number Theory

Tags: matrices, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm studying for an exam on abstract algebra, and I found a activity which asked you to discuss if the following matrix is invertible:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
54401 & 65432 & 45530 & 45678\\
34567 & 12121 & 11111 & 12345\\
12345 & 76543 & 98760 & 65456\\
43211 & 45678 & 88888 & 98765
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

I can detect certain partterns in the matrix. However, this question was included in the section of the Integer's Ring and as a hint the activity proposes to do a reduction modulo certain integer. First of all, I can't see a direct relation between singular matrices and $\mathbb Z/(n)$ (maybe for finding linear combinations(?), but I'm not sure). I would thank any hint or possible approach to the activity.

Comment: If the determinant is non-zero modulo some integer, the determinant must itself be non-zero, and hence be invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider $A$ and $\det(A)$ modulo $2$. It is easy to see that $\det(A)\equiv 1 \bmod 2$. In particular, $\det(A)\neq 0$.